# Shopify checkout api not working

Tags: shopify

it seems the checkout API is not working..

checked on browser (https://< store name >/admin/checkouts.json) and it returns error ({"errors": "Error"})

Also checked through gem shopify_api (version 3.0.3)

- ShopifyAPI::Order.count: gives me count of orders
- ShopifyAPI::Order.all: gives me orders
- ShopifyAPI::Checkout.count: gives error (ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found.)
- ShopifyAPI::Checkout.all: gives error (ActiveResource::ServerError: Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error.)

I am working with Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 3.2.6.

Thanks and Regards
Sumit Garg

Comment: This is working after a fix is pushed from Shopify